# comparacion de 2 predicados Prolog

Tags: prolog

quería hacer comparaciones de dos predicados, ejemplo:
A=s(s(s(0))) y B=s(s(s(s(s(0))) donde la condicion correcta es A <= B, no sé como tengo que realizar esto, pero si que tengo la mente clara de que se trata de una unify pero no se como representarlo en codigos.

mis codigos:

```
comparar_dimensiones(A,E):-
A=X,
E=Y,
X=Y.
```

Sé que esto está mal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Prolog, los predicados `(=)/2` y `(\=)/2` representan respectivamente la unificación y la negación de la misma.

El estándar define un orden entre términos, que puedes comprobar mediante los siguientes predicados incorporados:

- [(==)/2](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/==/2) – Term identical.
- [(@<)/2](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/@%3C/2) – Term less than.
- [(@=<)/2](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/@=%3C/2) – Term less than or equal to.
- [(@>)/2](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/@%3E/2) – Term greater than.
- [(@>=)/2](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/@%3E=/2) – Term greater than or equal to.
- [compare/3](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/compare/3) – Compare two terms according to order.
- [(\==)/2](http://tau-prolog.org/documentation/prolog/builtin/%5C==/2) – Term not identical.

Donde en tu caso, podrías comparar los dos términos como `A @=< B`.

Comment: Ya lo tengo, pero gracias.